# Why my Fortran power calculation routine in double precision is faster than in float precision?

Tags: performance, gcc, fortran

I found that the power calculation a**b is faster than dble(a)**dble(b), where a and b are in float precision. Why? My compiler is

```
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man
 --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla
 --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release
 --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions
 --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto
 --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install
 --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install
 --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86
_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
```

Here is my test code:

```
module  func
    real,parameter:: b=1.33
    real ::a(1000000)

contains  

! My test power calculation in float precision 
subroutine power(c)
    real:: c(:)
    integer :: i
    do i = 1, 1000000
        c(i) = a(i)**b
    enddo
end subroutine 

! My test power calculation in double precision (float converted into double)
subroutine hp_power(c)
    real:: c(:)
    integer :: i
    do i = 1, 1000000
        c(i) = dble(a(i))**dble(b)
    enddo
end subroutine 

end module

program compare
    use func
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    real :: c1(1000000), c2(1000000)
    real :: start_T,end_T

    !init the input array 
    do i = 1, 1000000
        a(i) = 3.!(3.+i*0.000001)
    end do

    call cpu_time(start_T)
        call power(c1)
    call cpu_time(end_T)  
    write(*,*) "The power running time is :,", end_T-start_T, 's', 'c(5):',c1(5)

    call cpu_time(start_T)
        call hp_power(c2)
    call cpu_time(end_T)  
    write(*,*) "The hp_power running time is :,", end_T-start_T, 's', 'c(5):',c2(5)
```

Comment: your question titles says exactly the opposite of the description. Which is it?

Comment: And report the timings and the optimisation settings for the code you've used.

Comment: And don't use `cpu_time` on a multi-core system. Use `system_clock` instead.

Comment: Using system_clock and executing the code inside a looping with hundred cycles and doing the average, I get different results in release, and consistent results in debug. In release, sometimes it is one routine faster, sometimes the other, and sometimes they took exactly the same time, while in debug the one with conversions are always slower. Which let me thinking the compiler, when optimizing, ignores the "double" conversion (as the result will be stored in a single precision array)

Comment: The `dble` function is old-fashioned and not portable. Improve the robustness of your code with`kind` parameters to control precision. You can get storage-based named parameter constants (`REAL32`, `REAL64`, and `REAL128`) from the intrinsic module `ISO_Fortran_env`, or `C_FLOAT`, and `C_DOUBLE`, `C_LONG_DOUBLE` from `ISO_C_binding`.

Comment: Thanks, I change `cpu_time` into `system_clock` and do the test again. The timings are as bellow.  **debug(-O0):** `power-> 1.41600017E-02 hp_power->1.06499996E-02`. **release(-O3):** `power->1.31200003E-02 hp_power->9.67000052E-03`

Answer (score 3):

Given the following adaptation of your code (compiled on an intel compiler), where I add a third routine, where the results are stored in an array of type double:

```
module  func
real,parameter:: b=1.33
real ::a(1000000)

contains  

! My test power calculation in float precision 
subroutine power(c)
real:: c(:)
integer :: i
do i = 1, 1000000
    c(i) = a(i)**b
enddo
end subroutine 

! My test power calculation in double precision (float converted into double)
subroutine hp_power(c)
real:: c(:)
integer :: i
do i = 1, 1000000
    c(i) = dble(a(i))**dble(b)
enddo
end subroutine 

! My test power calculation in double precision (float converted into double)
subroutine hp2_power(c)
real*8:: c(:)
integer :: i
do i = 1, 1000000
    c(i) = dble(a(i))**dble(b)
enddo
end subroutine 

end module

program compare
use func
implicit none
integer :: i
INTEGER :: count, count_2, count_rate, count_max
integer :: x
real c1_, c1_acc, c2_, c2_acc, c3_, c3_acc
real :: c1(1000000), c2(1000000)
real*8 :: c3(1000000)
real :: start_T,end_T

c1_acc = 0.0
c2_acc = 0.0
!init the input array 
do i = 1, 1000000
    a(i) = 3.!(3.+i*0.000001)
end do

do x = 1, 100
call system_clock(count, count_rate, count_max)
    call power(c1)
call system_clock(count_2, count_rate, count_max)  
c1_ = real(count_2-count)/count_rate
!write(*,*) "The power running time is :,", c1_, 's', 'c(5):',c1(5)
c1_acc = c1_acc + c1_

call system_clock(count, count_rate, count_max)
    call hp_power(c2)
call system_clock(count_2, count_rate, count_max)  
c2_ = real(count_2-count)/count_rate
!write(*,*) "The hp_power running time is :,", end_T-start_T, 's', 'c(5):',c2(5)
 c2_acc = c2_acc + c2_

call system_clock(count, count_rate, count_max)
    call hp2_power(c3)
call system_clock(count_2, count_rate, count_max)  
c3_ = real(count_2-count)/count_rate
!write(*,*) "The hp_power running time is :,", end_T-start_T, 's', 'c(5):',c2(5)
 c3_acc = c3_acc + c3_     
enddo

c2_ = real(c2_acc) / 100.0
c1_ = real(c1_acc) / 100.0
c3_ = real(c3_acc) / 100.0

write (*,*) c1_
write(*,*) c2_
write(*,*) c3_
end program Compare
```

In debug I get this kind of results:

power -> 2.0639971E-02

hp_power -> 2.7769983E-02

hp2_power -> 2.7449980E-02

While in release (with optimizations), these:

power -> 6.7950045E-03

hp_power -> 6.8100006E-03

hp2_power -> 1.6954981E-02

What is happening is that when optimizing, the conversion is ignored if the result will be stored in an array of type real. In hp2_Power, the result will be stored in an array of type real*8 (double), and thus this specific optimization can't be applied here (than the differences in time for this function).

I get consistent results all the time. In debug, the power function is always faster than the hp_power function, and the hp_power is almost the same to hp2_power, while in release, hp2_power is always slow, while power is very similar to hp_power.

As other things interfere with the times, you need to do many repetitions to be sure. When I look to individual times (from repetitions), the times vary a little and power and hp_power sometimes have the exactly same times.

Comment: Is there anything interesting to say when compiled with `-fp-model source`?

Comment: In release, with fp-model set to source the results are consistent with the ones found in debug. power is always faster, and hp and hp2_power are very similar, yet all of them faster than in debug.

Comment: In debug the change has no effect as the optimizations are OFF.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your modified code with an Intel compiler and got the similar result as you in both debug and release. But when I compile  the code with the GNU compiler, the result shows that *power* is always slower than *hp_power* and *hp2_power*  in both debug and release.   Here is my result. **debug(-O0)** : `power-> 1.41600017E-02 hp_power->1.06499996E-02 hp2_power->1.05300006E-02` **release(-O3)** : `power->1.31200003E-02 hp_power->9.67000052E-03 hp2_power->9.68000013E-03`

Comment: My CPU platform is Intel Xeon and my OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5

Comment: I have an arch (Intel i5), with gcc (don't know version now). I'll do some tests at night.

Comment: @YulongAo, just to add to the discussion, here is an article where some tests where made. http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/12/12_arit_speed/ With gcc 4.9 on one intel Xeon, they got the same thing: faster multiplication with 64 bits than 32 bits floating pointer numbers.